# How to make cucumber-rails use watir-webdriver instead of Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, watir-webdriver

I have been searching for a simple answer to this for a few days and can't seem to find an one, on either stackoverflow.com or google.  So, firstly, if this is answered elsewhere please point me in the correct direction.

So, I have a relatively new Rails 3 project using the cucumber-rails gem.  I am relatively new to Rails but have experience in Ruby and other web frameworks such as Sinatra and Ramaze.  My understanding is that out of the box, cucumber-rails uses Capybara for interacting with the web application and somehow does this without starting the rails server.  It somehow interacts with rack to simulate the requests.  Not sure if I have that entirely correct but I'm pretty sure it does not need a running rails server.

I am not a great fan of the Capybara DSL and I much prefer watir-webdriver which I have used in a few non rails projects (and non Ruby projects even).  However, I have not been able to find anywhere to show me how to swap out Capybara for watir-webdriver.

So my questions are these:

**Does the cucumber-rails gem have the ability to swap Capybara out for watir-webdriver?**

**If so, what is the best way to do this?**

**If not, does that mean I need to ditch cucumber-rails and just set cucumber with watir-webdriver up in my project manually?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't look hopeful from the [project description](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails):

> Rails Generators for Cucumber with special support for Capybara and DatabaseCleaner

And sure enough, it explicitly, unconditionally, loads Capybara [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/lib/cucumber/rails.rb#L23)

I think that means that you're going to need to hook it up yourself.

Having said that, I don't think there's anything stopping you from installing the gem, running `rails g cucumber:install`, and then replacing the Capybara-specific bits in the files it produces.

Comment: haha, yeh, it's pretty obvious there.  I'm aware that it's Capybara-centric.  I was wondering what the general practice was for people who prefer watir-webdriver - Whether there is something somewhere to tell cucumber-rails to use watir-webdriver, or whether they just ditch it and do it themselves.  Or even if there is a watir-webdriver centric gem .

Looks like hooking it up myself might be the way forward

Comment: I did see `watir-webdriver-rails` but this looked more specific to rspec as opposed to cucumber

Comment: Surely someone is doing this?  Anyone?  Noone users watir-webdriver and cucumber together in Rails?  Surely this can't be so.

Comment: As you can see from the RubyGems pages, [Capybara](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara) is *way* more popular than [Watir](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir) or [Watir-WebDriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver).